# Como utilizar o "find" do BeautifulSoup para encontrar uma tag script com tipo específico?

Tags: html, python, beautifulsoup

Há um tempo venho estudando como usar BeautifulSoup para conseguir encontrar conteúdo de tags etc.

Mas me deparei com um problema no qual o conteúdo que quero encontrar fica dentro de uma tag `<script type="text/javascript">` e apenas utilizando `find("script")`, ele encontra apenas as tags `<script>`, e, caso eu tente colocar `find("script type="text/javascript")`, o código dá erro.

```
def get_cod_produto(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.text
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')
    body = soup.body
    localizaScript = body.find('script type="text/javascript"')
    texto = localizaScript.string
    array = re.split('"', texto) 
    print(array)

get_cod_produto("https://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/listagem/listagem.cgi?string=rtx+2060&btnG=&pagina=2&ordem=3&limite=30&prime=false&marcas=[]&tipo_produto=[]&filtro=[]")
```

Ele retorna este erro quando eu coloco qualquer informação que não seja apenas `script`:

> ```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-565-dfa6bc29cef9> in <module>
> ----> 1 get_cod_produto("https://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/listagem/listagem.cgi?string=rtx+2060&btnG=&pagina=2&ordem=3&limite=30&prime=false&marcas=[]&tipo_produto=[]&filtro=[]")
>
> <ipython-input-564-5e17a520cf0d> in get_cod_produto(url)
>       5     body = soup.body
>       6     localizaScript = body.find('script type="text/javascript"')
> ----> 7     texto = localizaScript.string
>       8     array = re.split('"', texto)
>       9     print(array)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
> ```

Como posso fazer para puxar as informações dessa tag?

Comment: Nunca usei BeautifulSoup, mas se o método `find` for baseado em seletores CSS válidos, consigo explicar o porquê do problema. Basicamente, `script type="text/javascript"` **não** é um seletor CSS válido. Se você quiser limitar a busca de uma tag a um certo _atributo_ (como o atributo `type`), deve envolver o nome deste entre **colchetes**. Assim: `script[type="text/javascript"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_cod_produto(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.text
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')
    return soup.find('script', type="text/javascript")

get_cod_produto("https://www.kabum.com.br/cgi-local/site/listagem/listagem.cgi?string=rtx+2060&btnG=&pagina=2&ordem=3&limite=30&prime=false&marcas=[]&tipo_produto=[]&filtro=[]")
```

Basta fazer: `soup.find('script', type="text/javascript")`.

Como a documentação nos mostra: `Method signature: find(name, attrs, recursive, string, **kwargs)`

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Boa noite Lucas! Por nada! Abraço!